# How to run iMacros with looping at multiple tab?

Tags: loops, tabs, imacros

Dear All Member and Admin at stackoverflow,,
i want to ask ,
how to make iMacros script running with looping at multiple tab,
it make our work more easy and fast when we can Play Loop a iMacros script at multiple tab, 
Ex, i just thinking when 1st Loop until 3rd Loop run, the browser open 3 tab , tab 1 with 1st loop, tab 2 with 2nd loop, and tab 3 with 3th loop, after it, the tab is close automated and continue with 4th loop, and more,, thanks guys for the attention, :)

its my script ,

```
VERSION BUILD=8890130 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0

SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER ;
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\dell\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\java-store\1.csv

SET !LOOP 1

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
WAIT SECONDS=0

URL GOTO=https://www.bukalapak.com/products/new 

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:product_name CONTENT={{!COL1}}

WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=NAME:radio-suggestion CONTENT=YES

'TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:* CONTENT=${{!COL2}}

'TAG POS=2 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:* CONTENT=${{!COL3}}

'TAG POS=3 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:* CONTENT=${{!COL4}}

wait seconds=0

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:product_images_upload[data]&&TABINDEX:-1 CONTENT=C:\Users\dell\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\java-store\{{!COL5}}

TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:product_images_upload[data]&&TABINDEX:-1 CONTENT=C:\Users\dell\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\java-store\{{!COL6}}

TAG POS=3 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:product_images_upload[data]&&TABINDEX:-1 CONTENT=C:\Users\dell\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\java-store\{{!COL7}}

TAG POS=4 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=NAME:product_images_upload[data]&&TABINDEX:-1 CONTENT=C:\Users\dell\Documents\iMacros\Datasources\java-store\{{!COL8}}

WAIT SECONDS=2

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:product_new CONTENT=${{!COL9}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:product_weight CONTENT={{!COL10}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:product_stock CONTENT={{!COL11}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:product_price CONTENT={{!COL12}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:product_description_bb CONTENT={{!COL13}}

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=ID:product_product_detail_attributes_type_women CONTENT=YES

WAIT SECONDS=0

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:new_product ATTR=*

TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}

SET !EXTRACT NULL

TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:text-red&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT

SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:Barang<SP>telah<SP>berhasil<SP>ditambahkan.
```

Comment: You cannot run independent loops in different tabs, but you can try to play them in different windows of the same browser.

Comment: yes thats it right,, :) but i think this is a one script, :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is IT CAN'T.

But here is what you can do. Create multiple Macros folders. Such as:

```
My Documents\iMacros\MacrosProfileA\
My Documents\iMacros\MacrosProfileB\
My Documents\iMacros\MacrosProfileC\
```

Then create multiple FireFox profiles. You can use profileManager for that.

Here is how.

[image]

On each profiles in imacros settings change the working folder matching the above given paths. You can do that on your own.

Then create shortcuts on Desktop to match each profiles. Then place the scripts in each of the folders. Then run each of the profiles and you will be able to run multiple iMacros scripts from each Firefox WINDOW.

There is more to this explanation but with little of your effort you can make it work.

Comment: i've been used mulltifox for loong time, yes it really helpfull, but i want to improve this script to fastest when us work, but thanks for the attention guys,, :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes you can, I just discovered that myself, by trial and error - the downside is that you will have to paste all commands all over again, like so:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Disable<SP>active<SP>checks<SP>of<SP>this<SP>service
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:cmd.cgi ATTR=NAME:btnSubmit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Done
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Submit<SP>passive<SP>check<SP>result<SP>for<SP>this<SP>servi*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:cmd.cgi ATTR=NAME:plugin_output CONTENT=Currently<SP>disabled
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:cmd.cgi ATTR=NAME:btnSubmit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Done
TAB T=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Disable<SP>active<SP>checks<SP>of<SP>this<SP>service
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:cmd.cgi ATTR=NAME:btnSubmit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Done
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Submit<SP>passive<SP>check<SP>result<SP>for<SP>this<SP>servi*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:cmd.cgi ATTR=NAME:plugin_output CONTENT=Currently<SP>disabled
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:cmd.cgi ATTR=NAME:btnSubmit
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Done
```

Please note that TAB = 1 means current tab and it will start counting to the right.
http://wiki.imacros.net/upload/d/db/Ie_tab_support.png